# node.js send userid client to server

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

Im having trouble to send the client costum userid to the node.js

For some reason it wont send the userid to the server to submit it. there is no output for it from the node log.

client sided:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://sitename.eu:1337/');

var user_id = <?echo $data->userid?>;


socket.on('connection',function(user_id) {
    socket.emit('setuserid', user_id);

});
```

server sided:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket){ // just to prove that the code is inside it

logger.info('SocketIO > Connected socket ' + socket.id);


socket.on('setuserid', function (userId) {
    users[userId]=socket;
    socket.userid = userId;
    logger.info("setting userid...");
});
```

only output:

```
2015-07-12T21:09:05.656Z - info: SocketIO > Connected socket E2ghiXGfTJWtgWs4AAAA
2015-07-12T21:09:08.134Z - info: SocketIO > Connected socket XY0c-A_ZveEUs_CuAAAB
2015-07-12T21:09:21.393Z - info: SocketIO > Disconnected socket E2ghiXGfTJWtgWs4AAAA
2015-07-12T21:09:22.610Z - info: SocketIO > Connected socket G3DmRKSymCuaximOAAAC
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

`socket.on('connection',function(user_id) {`

into:

`socket.on('connect',function() {`

Socket.io triggers an event called `connect` (http://socket.io/docs/client-api/#io#emitter). Since `connection` is never called, that function never gets run.

In addition, make sure you remove the `user_id` as a parameter.

Otherwise, you overwrite the global scope and will be sending `undefined` as a result for userid

Comment: So if i make your changes it will work? If not , caused by connection never is called how should i do this?

Comment: so how can i change it to automatically send userid to the node?

Comment: @maria, did you make the changes and test?

Comment: yes i did. for make it work i had to go server sided and call the connection to the client at the end.